# Primes with degree one

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For any positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the number of primes $p$ such that $p\mid n$ but $p^2\not\mid n$. For example $f(2)=f(3)=1$ and $f(4)=0$. For any positive integer $k$ and $m$, is there $a$ such that $f(a)=f(a+1)=\dots=f(a+m-1)=k$?

For $m=1$ this is easy, as we can simply set $a=p_1p_2\dots p_k$ for some primes of our choice.

Comment: An OEIS sequence: https://oeis.org/A056169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any interval of length $> ((k+1)\#)^2$ (where the "primorial" $t\#$ is the product of the first $t$ primes) there is an integer $x$ congruent to $p_j \mod p_j^2$ for each of the first $k+1$ primes $p_j$, and thus with $f(x) \ge k+1$.